# Find out what users DIDN'T submit in input field.

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine, autocomplete, submit

I'm using Jquery autocomplete on an input field. So, as users type out a word, they can see a drop-down list showing fewer and fewer choices to select from.

The thing is, sometimes the user's input will not be among the choices in that list. I believe that when users see that list go empty, they will give up on their original search term and either enter a different one, or simply delete it and leave the field blank.

When that happens, I want to know what was the original search term entered?

(Because after collecting that info over time, I plan to add the most popular ones to the list, for future users to choose from)

So my question is, what is the best way to find out what users typed in, but didn't submit?

My idea so far is to listen for when the user takes the focus off the input field, and get it's value on change. That will tell me about users who deleted and left it blank, but it still doesnt tell me anything for the users who deleted and then entered a new term.

Is there a better solution?

PS - My site is on GAE, so if using python opens any relevant doors... there's that too.

Comment: I doubt your predictions will happen , anyone on the internet is used to seeing Google's and YouTube's autocomplete and understand to submit even if it is not a popular search term

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain very well. The nature of my website is, that by the time users get to the point where they are selecting (products to buy) from this list, they will already understand that if its not in the list - then it's not available for purchase yet. I want to determine what will be the most important product for me to add next to the offering, based on how many people are wanting it. I can only add 1 new product per month, so I'm trying please as many customers as possible.

Comment: ok, thanks for clarifying , that makes sense , I think you may get better information on what to add by making a link that says "Didn't find what your looking for?"   then a simple text box to add suggestion , but reguardless @Michael Dibbets has answer for your specific question

Answer (score 1):

You could add a keystroke event listener and simply listen to the backspace keypress event.
When that happens, save and ajax the form field value to your server for storage.

**EDIT:** On basis of Scott Selby's anser:
To cover all bases:
Event listener for keypress backspace

Event listener for selection start and end. Save and ajax the selected part if if the form field has changed on the next keypress.

Catch onunload event, safe form data if exists.

That way you always get what the users deleted. This also helps making your search query window "typo" proof because you'll be able to spot "common" mistakes over time.

It's also a good way to collect data on what products or services your potential clients expect from you.

Comment: that still won't help with CTRL+A then retype in box , or with mouse select all text and begin to retype

Comment: Err, event listener? You can capture multiple keypresses. That has been around sinds the 90's... In fact, it was one of the first things I learned in javascript, because form specific event listeners werent there yet.
And mouse select can also be caputured and you can even save just the selected part. That's kind of a non argument @ScottSelby